# storing button and other wx widgets in array

Tags: python, wxpython

How can I store button, listbox and other wxpython widgets in an array? My problem is something like this:
I have a list such as list1=[a, b,c,d,....n].
I want to iterate through the first loop and use that as a label for by button. My approach was

```
Button_Array=[]
for i in List1:
    New_Button=wx.Button(panel,-1,label=list1[i])
    Button_Array.append(New_Button)
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you wanted something like this:

```
Button_Array=[]
for i in List1:
    New_Button=wx.Button(panel,-1,label=i)
    Button_Array.append(New_Button)
```

Note that when you loop over a list, the "i" is each item in the list, which in this case is a string. I would rename "i" to "lbl" to make it clearer what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that you are writing

```
for i in List1
```

and then using

```
label = list1[i]
```

It should (I haven't tested it) work if you instead write

```
label = i
```

Keep in mind when you write

```
for i in list1
```

you are iterating over elements of the list, not the indices.